# Accessing an Android watch via USB COM port through command line to install applications on it

Tags: adb, bluetooth

I have a Goclever watch that runs a dummy Android. It has a USB and Bluetooth, but no Wi-Fi. It has no device info in its menu and the .apk files are not installable from its file manager (only mp3 and jpeg files can be opened). When plugging it to my Windows desktop it's recognized as a MediaTek USB COM port device, but `adb devices` returns an empty list.

Is there a way to somehow hack into it via command line, installing applications from .apk files onto it? I need at least Sleep as Android, because though the watch has its internal accelerometer it's not acting in behalf of the phone's accelerometer (so whenever I launch Sleep as Android on my phone the sensor signals are not picked up by it).

BTNotification is up and running perfectly, the selected applications keep pushing the notifications to the watch and even phone calls can be made through it.

The BT device list in my phone identifies the watch as 6261 so I guess it has an MTK 6261 processor in it though I'm not completely sure.

UPDATE: upon `*#8375#` I get the following:

```
[VERSION]
NX9_61D_240_V1_8_XWDZ_W02Z_CHRONOS_32_T9_L2_C5_B_IPS_160921
[BRANCH]:
11CW13522MP
GPLUS61A_11C_NX9
BUILD: BUILD_NO
SERIAL#:
[BUILD TIME]:
2016/09/21 18:42
[MRE VERSION] 3100
HAL_VERNO:
```

Comment: What OS does the computer run on?

Comment: The desktop has a 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium. I have absolutely no info about what version of Android is running on the watch.

Comment: Do you happen to have a Mac? Macs do not require drivers to use ADB.

Comment: Sorry, no Mac. What else could Windows require in order to recognize the watch as a full blown Android device so that ADB sees it?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do. Windows requires that the manufacturer creates custom software for the PC to talk to the phone using ADB.

Comment: I see. Any ideas where I could look around to find some specs by which I could write myself a driver for the watch?

Comment: You can't. Only the manufacturer knows the exact behavior of the device at that level (kernel level, which is closed-source) and the driver would have to be written in assembly, a language very few programmers use today. Sorry.